# Support for taproot multisig descriptors

Tags: multi-signature, taproot, schnorr-signatures, output-script-descriptors

I’m trying to understand the current state of descriptor support for taproot, with a specific focus on multisig wallets (When I say “multisig” I mean k-of-n threshold signing, rather than a schnorr multisignature). I found this PR that introduced taproot descriptors into Core: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/22051 and it said that support for more interesting scripts had not yet been implemented. Is that still the case, or does anyone know of any docs or examples to do a multisig wallet descriptor?

Thanks!

Comment: There are two docs in core repository related to multisig that use descriptors in examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing (January 2022) there hasn't been a descriptor specified for Schnorr/Taproot multisig (using the new OP_CHECKSIGADD opcode specified in [BIP 342](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0342.mediawiki)) or using the key aggregation scheme MuSig.

> (When I say “multisig” I mean k-of-n threshold signing, rather than a schnorr multisignature)

A clarification on terminology. In Bitcoin we generally use "multisig" to refer to n-of-n (n=n) and "threshold" to refer to k-of-n (k<n). MuSig(2) refers to a key aggregation scheme where only one key and one signature go onchain despite there being multiple keys involved offchain. Threshold equivalents of MuSig(2) are being worked on e.g. FROST but are not finalized or as mature as MuSig(2). Neither MuSig(2) or FROST have descriptors specified at the time or writing.

Hence if you want to use a multisig or threshold signature descriptor you would use an existing one e.g. `multi` or `sortedmulti` that doesn't support a Schnorr/Taproot multisig. A bit confusingly the `multi` descriptor does support both multisignature and threshold signatures according to the above definitions but not for Schnorr/Taproot.

**April 2023 Update**

There are now `multi_a` and `sortedmulti_a` [descriptors](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/24043/) supported in the Bitcoin Core wallet for k-of-n policies using the CHECKSIGADD opcode inside the `tr()` Taproot descriptor. A MuSig(2) descriptor has been [discussed](https://gist.github.com/sipa/06c5c844df155d4e5044c2c8cac9c05e#musig-descriptors) and there is an open [pull request](https://github.com/rust-bitcoin/rust-miniscript/pull/460) in rust-miniscript implementing it but it hasn't yet been finalized.

Comment: Not related to the question so putting in the comments but Miniscript does differentiate between multisig and threshold sig (`multi` and `thresh`) but descriptors allow you to do both multisig and threshold sig using the `multi` descriptor. That will be confusing when MIniscript gets integrated with descriptors :)

Comment: I think traditionally in Bitcoin "multisig" refers to k-of-n using OP_CHECKMULTISIG (so using multiple signatures and multiple keys). In cryptography at large, "multisignature" refers to a single signature with multiple keys (which musig/musig2/musig-dn and other schemes achieve), and "threshold signature" refers to a single signature corresponding to a k-of-n combination of multiple keys (like FROST accomplishes).

Comment: @PieterWuille: Ok you may have changed your definitions since https://btctranscripts.com/lets-talk-bitcoin-podcast/2019-06-09-ltb-pieter-wuille-jonas-nick/ :) "k-of-n is say 2 out of 3 where k is different from n" and "When we talk about k-of-n or thresholds"

Comment: that's saying the same thing?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought within bitcoin, “multisig” traditionally referred to threshold signing, for example: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/descriptors.md#multisig . In any case, the clarification is helpful :)

Comment: There is a [multi_a](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/24043) descriptor now.

Comment: @nikicat: Thanks. Updated answer.